# Swift rand() not being random

Tags: random, swift

Today is my first day with Swift, and I have run into a problem. I am using rand to generate a random number, but it is giving me the same results every time I run the code.

main.swift:

```
import Foundation

var player = Player()

for _ in 1..6 {
    println(player.kick())
}
```

player.swift:

```
import Foundation

class Player {
    var health = 25
    var xp = 15
    var upgrades = ["kick": 0, "punch": 0]

    func kick() -> Int {
        let range = (3, 7)
        let damage = Int(rand()) % (range.1 - range.0) + range.0 + 1
        return damage
    }

    func punch() -> Int {
        let range = (4, 6)
        let damage = Int(rand()) % (range.1 - range.0) + range.0 + 1
        return damage
    }
}
```

Every time I run the code, it logs these numbers:

```
7
5
5
6
6
```

I also tried this: `Int(arc4random(range.1 - range.0)) + range.0 + 1` but it said it couldn't find an overload for + that accepts the supplied arguments

I have no idea why this would be happening. I'd appreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: __NEVER__ use `rand`. use `arc4random`

Comment: I tried using that with this `Int(arc4random(range.1 - range.0)) + range.0 + 1` but it said it couldn't find an overload for + that accepts the supplied arguments

Comment: are let variables lexical? if not, could let's immutability be biting you?

Comment: @addison thats different problem. you may need `Int()` everywhere

Comment: This determinism is in fact a *nice feature* when one is developing a program, as it is much easier to debug a program that behaves the same way each time one runs it. In most applications it is not important to have a very accurate random number generator, in those apps, *use rand()*, not arc4random, and *don't seed the generator in debug-mode.*

Comment: @ragnarius If you want replicability for debugging or for covariance induction strategies in Monte Carlo, use Mersenne Twister from gamekit.  `rand` isn't even standardized, so you don't get portability (unlike Mersenne Twister), and the typical implementation is a 32 bit LCG with some pretty bad statistical properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should never use `rand()`, use `arc4random` - it's a much better generator.  If you check its man-pages, you'll find that it has an integer range generator form called `arc4random_uniform()`, which you should use to avoid modulo bias when the modulus is not a power of 2.  I believe the following is what you want, it worked for me in playground:

```
let damage = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.1 - range.0) + 1) + UInt32(range.0)
```

The `+ 1` is because the upper end of `arc4random_uniform()` is non-inclusive.  If your range is `(4,7)`, this should give occurrences of 4, 5, 6, and 7.

Answer (score 8):

`rand()` in most programming environments gives you a repeatable sequence of pseudo-random numbers, by design. Look for a function called `seed` or `srand` for ways to initialize the random number generator.

Answer (score -2):

Using `rand()` is fine, you can seed the pseudo-random number generator with this call at the beginning of your program:

```
srand(UInt32(time(nil)))
```

Comment: 'srand' is unavailable in Swift: Use arc4random instead (Xcode 8 / iOS 10 / Swift 3)